# CSS Bootstrap. Fixed and Fluid div, fluid inner content seems offset

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create what I assumed was a basic template. I have a sidebar that is fixed width and absolutely position to the left. I then have a 100% width div absolutely position next to that.

When I put content in side the right sidebar and add a `margin: 0 auto` it seems to align right.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is my css/html:

```css
/* Structure */

#left,
#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  left: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

main.container-fluid {
  max-width: 960px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">

</div>
<div id="right">
  <main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Btw, I'm a noob. If there is another/best practice way to achieve a fixed sidebar and fluid right side please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider an approach like this.

Instead of using absolute positioning, just put your `.sidebar` and `.main` inside a flex container.

Give `.sidebar` a flex-basis of 250px, and `.main` a flex-basis of auto. Both can shrink, but only `.main` can grow.

Then inside `.main`, add your bootstrap `.container-fluid` and start using `.row` and `.col` wherever you need.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.bg--red {
  background: red;
}

.bg--blue {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

.bg--yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="sidebar  bg--red">
    <h2>sidebar content</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="main  bg--blue">
    <h1>main content</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col  bg--yellow">col 1 / 3</div>
        <div class="col  bg--yellow">col 2 / 3</div>
        <div class="col  bg--yellow">col 3 / 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```